# TransferText export to CSV not working, but TransferSpreadsheet to XLSX working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I created a Form in which I created a button and through the context menu I activated the Code-generator for VBA.
On a click on the button, the query is correctly exported as .xlsx:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Befehl0_Click()

            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "queryname", "C:\test\queryname.xlsx", -1

End Sub
```

However, when I modify the export (according to this [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958(v=office.15).aspx)):

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Befehl0_Click()

            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "queryname", "C:\test\queryname.csv", -1

End Sub
```

Nothing happens.

I've also tried setting an Export Specification, but that doesn't help either.

What is wrong here?

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: check your queryname, check if you have access to save on your destination folder, check if destination folder exists..

Comment: @krishKM There is no error message, and the issues in your second comment are non-issues because I can export the .xslx just fine with all the same queryname, folder, destination.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line does it run the line?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid hmm I don't think so. When I put both export functions after each other (CSV first XLSX second) then the excel is not exported, so I think the program aborts at the CSV line. In the Direct-Window (Ctrl+G), when I try to run the line I actually do get an error '3441' "Text file specification field separator matches decimal separator or text delimiter". When I add a Specification in that window, I get error 3625 "No specification found with that name". So I googled again and apparently you have to save the specification during "advanced options" while exporting not thereafter...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was that there was an error '3441' "Text file specification field separator matches decimal separator or text delimiter", which was only visible when trying to run it in the Direct-window (Ctrl+G).

Apparently, when you use a non-English OS this is a problem with the default setting for the delimiters.

To solve it, an Export Specification has to be provided. However, there are two ways to create such, one of which is wrong.

The same is true for importing, for which I found this [on the web:](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_27589759.html)

> "Yes i had created the Specification and it is viewable via the Import
>   Wizard, however there is no line for it in MSysIMEXSpecs."  Then it
>   seems that you may not have created a true import Specification.
>
> In Access 2007 and newer you can also save the "Import Steps".  This
>   *is not* the same thing as in Import Specification.
>
> A "Saved Import", will not show up in MSysIMEXSpecs, but a true
>   Import specification should.
>
> To be sure, ...*during* the import process steps, if you click the
>   "Advanced" button to actually create the Import Specification.
>
> The last step of the import process is the "Save Import Steps" dialog
>   box, ...again, this is *not* the same thing as an Import Spec.  A
>   "Saved Import/export" will be available under: 
>       External Data-->Export-->Saved Export  ...so check here as well

Using this knowledge, it works by adding the Export Specification "exportcsv" created in the above process.

```
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "exportcsv", "queryname", "C:\test\queryname.csv", -1
```